# How to create a recommender based on tags?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I am working on an e-learning platform using PHP. It recommends videos, if you fail a specific question. How do i go about creating the recommender system that takes in Tags and recommends relevant Videos?

```
import pandas as pd

videos = pd.read_csv("/file_path/vid_com_dup.csv",
                 sep = ',', names = 
 ['vid_id','ques_id','vid_name','vid_tags'])
videos.head()
```

The csv file includes the following columns:

1. vid_id - primary key and id for videos.
2. ques_id - foreign key.
3. vid_name - the name of the video.
4. vid_tags - some tags in form of (1+1,single digit, addition, grade 1).

the tags above are also in question table which are similar.

if question has tags (1+1,single digit, addition, grade 1), I want to make 
recommender that takes in above tags compares with different videos that have similar tags and gives recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got Around it, hope it will help someone else.

1. Load Data set: Image of Sample Dataset:
   [image]
2. Split the tags: image of split tags:
   [image]
   Basically what the above picture depicts is that if the tag is present is 1 else 0.
3. Scale and Transform the Features matrix above:
   [image]
4. Apply Scikit learn unsupervised nearest neighbors. You should get indices and distance matrix. What is unsupervised nearest neighbors? For this problem we are only interested in getting nearest neighbours based on distances and recommending and not for classifying. Image of indices and distances below:
   [image]
5. Your all done. All is needed now is a function for you to get nearest videos. This is depicted in the image below that has code and result.
   [image]